# How to configure nginx to try_files first, if not exists follow the request_uri

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, page-caching

We have page caches with id partitioning and subdomain. Say for requests like `ny.site.com/cat/12345` or `la.site.com/dog/234`, nginx need to

1. check if file `/cat/ny/1234/5.html` exists, return it
2. otherwise, just use the original `request_uri` to hit the app server, and the cache file will be created

We managed to figure out the subdomain and id partitioning part, but didn't get any luck on the try_files part. Always get indefinite loop errors like `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to`

our nginx.conf file is like

```
rewrite "/cat/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{1,4})" /system/cache/cat/$subdomain/$1/$2.html break;
rewrite "/cat/([0-9]{1,4})" /system/cache/cat/$subdomain/$1.html break;
try_files $uri $request_uri;
```

Any hints? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I tried the following. Nginx was looking for $request_uri (e.g., /cat/12345) in the file system instead of hitting the app server. Any thoughts?

```
try_files $uri @old;
location @old {
    rewrite ^ $request_uri break;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this

```
location ^~ ^/cat/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{1,4}) {

    try_files "/cat/ny/$1/$2.html" @app_server;

}
location @app_server{

    # pass this to your app server for processing.

}
```

1. Use ^~ as this will also include the edge case like /cat/12345/ (ending slash).
2. And just be sure whether you want $uri (which is without query string) or $request_uri
   ( which contains query string).

Comment: @surajs21: I have url like `www.test.com/public/` and `www.test.com/public/web` and `www.test.com/public/web1`. this is ZF2 I am facing issue like it properly get link to first URL 'public/' but issue with `www.test.com/public/web` and `www.test.com/public/web1`. ngin x not able to map it. Please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377321/nginx-no-input-file-specified-php-fast-cgi

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this my self before but this is how I would write it

```
location / { # or whatever location you see fit to your requirements
    try_files $uri.html $uri;
    # I don't know if the `.` needs to be escaped `$uri\.html`, you can try both
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but I don't get it. How would this try_files solve the problem? i.e., when $uri doesn't exist on disk, go back to the original $request_uri?

Comment: `try_files` tells nginx what to try for that request, so i'm simply telling it to see if the `$uri` has an html file for it, otherwise try `$uri`, If you have a php file that handles the requests then u should pass that as a 3rd parameter ie: `/index.php$request_uri` for example