# Nginx at ECS gives 'No input file specified'

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ecs

I deployed a docker container with nginx and drupal, everything works fine in my local computer but at Amazon ECS with fargate, it only displays 'No input file specified'

Here is how starts the default.conf

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/app/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name _;

    sendfile off;
    server_tokens off;

    # Add stdout logging
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    # reduce the data that needs to be sent over network
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json text/javascript application/x-javascript  application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a php cgi issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377321/nginx-no-input-file-specified-php-fast-cgi